# Django Crontab : How to stop parallel execution

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cron

I have few cronjobs running with the help of django-crontab. Let us take one cronjob as an example, suppose this job A is scheduled to run every two minutes.

However, while the job is running and if it is not finished in two minutes, I do not want another instance of this job to execute.

Exploring few resources, I came across this article, but I am not sure where to fit this in.

```
https://bencane.com/2015/09/22/preventing-duplicate-cron-job-executions/
```

Did someone already came across this issue? How did you fix it?

Comment: Is it [this library](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab) that you're using?

Comment: I am using this https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the readme](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab), you should be able to set:

```
CRONTAB_LOCK_JOBS = True
```

in your Django settings. That will prevent a new job instance from starting if a previous one is still running.